# Question on $\ell_2$ and $\ell_1 $ norms

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

> Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times N}$ be such that, for some constants $0 , \rho < 1$ and $\tau \geq 0,$
>   $$\| v_{S} \|_{2} \leq \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{s}} \| v_{\overline{S}}\|_{1} + \tau \|A^{*}A \|_{\infty}~\textrm{for all}~S \subset  [N]~\textrm{and all}~v \in \mathbb{C}^N.$$
>   Here $[N]$ is an index set, $\{ 1,2, \dots , N \}.$ For $x \in \mathbb{C}^N,$ let $y=Ax+e$ for some $e \in \mathbb{C}^m$ with $\| A^{*} e \|_{\infty} \leq \eta.$
>   Let $\tilde{x}$ be a minimizer of 
>   $$\min_{z \in \mathbb{C}^N} \| z \|_1~\textrm{subject to}~\| A^{*}(Az - y)  \|_{\infty} \leq \eta.$$
>   Show that 
>   $$\| x - \tilde{x} \|_2 \leq \frac{C \sigma_{s}(x)_1}{\sqrt{s}}+D \eta,$$
>   for constants $C,D >0$ depending only on $\rho$ and $\tau.$

Here $\sigma_s(x)_{p}=\inf_{\| z \|_{0} \leq s} \| x -z \|_p$  is the $\ell_p - $error of best $s-$term approximation to $x \in \mathbb{C}^N$.

Hello everyone, this is my first time here. I'll be thankful if anyone can give me a suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: This is the fundamental theorem concerning the accuracy of the Danzig selector under noise given its adherence to the RIP property. (Note that you haven't defined $S$ and $\bar{S}$). I suggest you consult the original paper; since the authors are not active on the forum, I strongly suspect that's what anyone else here would have to do. In fact, really, a correct answer to the question *is an entire paper*.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, thank you for the suggestion. It is exactly Danzig selector. $S$ is defined already and $\overline{S}$  is the complement of $S$ in $[N].$

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the definition of $S$. Still, I think this is not the right forum for you: you need Candes or colleagues...

Comment: I see. This is from one of the problems from the text book http://human-robot.sysu.edu.cn/ebook/preprint093.pdf.

Comment: OK, that's crazy. If that is even remotely appropriate for homework it is because most of the answer is already given in the preceding text.

Comment: Welcome aboard! Advice: you should have stated in your problem that you're dealing with Danzig selector (Candès and Tao 2000 and X). And clearly state how what you're trying to do is different from the bounds established in that paper. This reduces the attentional load and saves time for everybody, and you're more like to get directions.

Comment: BTW, what's $v_s$ ? Your question is not self-contained.

Comment: @dohmatob, $v_S$ is the value of the vector $v$ on the index set $S \subset [N].$